# Creating a Delaunay Triangulation around Polygons

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry

It's possible to [create a Delaunay Triangulation in python](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) from a set of points, but how can I do the same for a set of polygons? For example, in the picture, I'd like to have the square be a kind of "obstacle", and generate the triangulation around that. I'd also like a way to know what the center point of each triangle is if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Claim.** This is not possible in general.

*Proof*. If no four points in your set of points are cocircular, then the Delaunay triangulation is unique. So as long as the obstacle polygon contains at least one non-Delaunay edge, you will not be able to arrive at the unique Delaunay triangulation of the point set. This is fairly easy to see:  Consider, as in the flip algorithm, a [quadrilateral in general position whose diagonal needs to be flipped](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Visual_Delaunay_definition:_Flipping) to be Delaunay. Now let one of the bad triangles be the obstacle and the set of the four vertices of the quadrilateral be the set of points. Then clearly, you can never arrive at a Delaunay triangulation.

**Update:** The problem you described is a special case of the [Constrained Delaunay Triangulation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation). In your case, the constrained edges are just the edges of the boundaries of your obstacles. There are a number of python libraries that can do this. For example

- [CGAL-swig-bindings](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings): Probably capable of doing this, [because CGAL can](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#Section_2D_Triangulations_Constrained_Delaunay).
- [poly2tri](https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/)
- [Python Triangle](http://dzhelil.info/triangle/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In general, answers here should not have "exercises".

Comment: @Sneftel thanks! I have updated my answer to complete the proof.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the full triangulation first and then removing the edges you don't want. For example:

1. Compute the [Constrained Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation) with all the points included
2. Identify the boundary of your "exclusion" polygon
3. Remove any edge that connects any two points in your exclusion polygon but is not part of the boundary itself

The assumes you still want the boundary of the exclusion polygon in the triangulation. Also, this may no longer be a Delaunay triangulation but just a polygon mesh.

As for the the center of each polygon, once you have the triangulation you can compute it using the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid).

Comment: Unless the poster computes the CDT instead of the DT, the boundary of the excluded polygon may not be contained in the triangulation.